# Why does a translated DFA usually not have $2^n$ states?

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

If we translate an NFA to a DFA, it can have $2^n$ states at the maximum. However, this usually does not happen? Why is that so and what is the condition such that the translated DFA will have $2^n$ states?

Comment: If you follow the power-set construction then the DFA will indeed have $2^n$ states...

Comment: Usually it does not. It is very rare that the translated DFA will have exactly $2^n$ states. My question is, why does it usually have less. @Math1000

Comment: I misspoke. You can see from this example that the power set construction *can* produce a DFA with $2^n$ states: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction#/media/File:NFA_and_blown-up_equivalent_DFA_01.svg

But as for why it may be less - some states in the power set of the NFA states may be unreachable, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound $2^n$ is indeed achieved by the automaton ${\mathcal A}_n =
(Q_n, A, E_n, \{0\}, \{0\})$, with $A = \{a, b\}$, $Q_n = \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ and 
\begin{multline*}
 E_n = \{(i, a, i+1) \mid 0 \leq i \leq n-1\} \cup \{(n-1, a, 0)\} \cup {}\\
 \{(i, b, i) \mid 1 \leq i \leq n-1\} \cup \{(i, b, 0) \mid 1 \leq i \leq
 n-1\}\}
\end{multline*}

Now, the problem with your question is that *usually* is not a mathematical term. It is actually a difficult question to find a rigorous model of *random NFA*. Such a model is proposed in [1], but the average complexity of the conversion NFA to DFA according to such a model is still an open problem, as far as I can know.

[1] P.C. Héam and J.-L. Joly, [On the uniform random generation of non deterministic automata up to isomorphism](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02797), *Implementation and application of automata*, 140-152, LNCS **9223**, Springer, Cham, (2015).